# Friends of friends use case - Redis vs a Graph Databse

Tags: redis, graph-databases, database, nosql

I made a small social network as part of an assignemt for school. Our next task is to implement a functionality into the project which will use a non-relational database. We were suggested to go for Redis or ElasticSearch.

It is clear to me, that I could use ElasticSearch to look for people and groups based on their names etc.

But at the moment I am more interested in making a potential friend finder which suggests friends based on common friends of the two users and maybe the groups they are part of.

My question is: Is this a good use-case for Redis or would it be much much better to use a Graph database for something like this?

This is how I imagined it:

- I have a Set of registered users called "users" stored inside redis
- For each user I have a Set which keeps track of their friends    e.g.
  "user:1:friends"
- I also have a SortedSet of potential friends stored for each user
  e.g. "user:1:potential"

Let's say a user I am not friends with will add one of my friends to their friends-list. When this happens I would take all the sets of friends of my friend and check if my friends new friend is part of each of the sets. If not, then I would increment the score assigned to his id in the sets of potential friends of my friends friends which are not friends with the new guy.

All in all this seems to me like a lot of work which is why I am not sure wether this is even a good idea.
So again- Would a graph database just be much better for somehting like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you'd have anything to implement (inlcuding setting up the no sql db) I would definitely go with graphDBs.
Friends of friends (and more generally suggestions) is a basic use case for this type of DB. It's were they show their full potential.
I'd suggest that you have a look at Neo4J: http://neo4j.com
And their social network use case: http://neo4j.com/use-cases/social-network/